# How to write the equivalent Sqlite statement for query given below?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my working non-sql query:

```
Query = "select Cust_Id,Card_Number,Clients_Title,Address_Current,Phone_Number,Mobile_Number from Customer_New Where 1=1";
try
{
    if (txt_title.Text != "")
        Query += " and Clients_Title Like '%" + txt_title.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_address.Text != "")
        Query += " and Address_Current Like '%" + txt_address.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_phone.Text != "")
        Query += " and Phone_Number Like '%" + txt_phone.Text + "%'";
    if (txt_mobile.Text != "")
        Query += " and Mobile_Number Like '%" + txt_mobile.Text + "%'";
    if (cbo_location.Text != "")
        Query += " and AreaLocation Like '%" + cbo_location.Text + "%'";
}

catch { }
```

In this code the working of "where" clause is:

- If all text boxes are null it selects all the records mean skip where
  clause
- if some text is entered in any 1 text box then section in 'where'
  clause is made on that particular text box
- if some text is entered in any multiple text box then section in
     'where' clause is made according to them by fulfilling "AND"
     condition between them .It mean all values entered into text boxes
     must match with corresponding rows attributes

> Here I am attempting to write its equivalent SQL statement .

```
SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM Customer_New
WHERE (@Clients_Title IS NULL   OR   Clients_Title    = @Clients_Title )
AND (@Address_Current IS NULL   OR   Address_Current  = @Address_Current )
AND (@Phone_Number    IS NULL   OR   Phone_Number     = @Phone_Number)
AND (@Mobile_Number   IS NULL   OR   Mobile_Number    = @Mobile_Number )
AND (@AreaLocation    IS NULL   OR   AreaLocation     = @AreaLocation)
```

Problem in this query is :

It search NULL or ''(empty string) from db tablt if nothing is provided in text box.I want as in above code if nothing entered in text box that attribute get skip from where clause and only values provided in text box are considered for checking in where clause.Can sql case and if else condition help in this scenario? Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this ? Thanks

Note : In sqlite stored procedure don't exit .So guide me to write the correct sql query according to scenario.

Comment: I have also tried this and got same result                     SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation FROM Customer_New WHERE (@Clients_Title = '' OR Clients_Title LIKE '%'+@Clients_Title+'%') AND (@Address_Current = '' OR Address_Current LIKE '%'+@Address_Current+'%') AND (@Phone_Number = '' OR Phone_Number LIKE '%'+@Phone_Number+'%') AND (@Mobile_Number = '' OR Mobile_Number LIKE '%'+@Mobile_Number+'%') AND (@AreaLocation = '' OR AreaLocation LIKE '%'+@AreaLocation+'%')

Comment: is your example not working ????

Comment: my nonsql-query working ..but i want is to write equivalent sql query...my sql query is not working

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditions

```
(@Clients_Title = ''
 OR ((@Clients_Title != '') AND (Clients_Title = @Clients_Title)
```

and so on.

Here's the full version

```
SELECT Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current,
       Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation FROM Customer_New 
WHERE (@Clients_Title = '' 
       OR (@Clients_Title != '' AND Clients_Title LIKE '%'+@Clients_Title+'%'))
  AND (@Address_Current = '' 
       OR (@Address_Current != '' AND Address_Current LIKE '%'+@Address_Current+'%'))
  AND (@Phone_Number = '' 
       OR (@Phone_Number != '' AND Phone_Number LIKE '%'+@Phone_Number+'%'))
  AND (@Mobile_Number = '' 
       OR (@Mobile_Number != '' AND Mobile_Number LIKE '%'+@Mobile_Number+'%'))
  AND (@AreaLocation = '' 
       OR (@AreaLocation != '' AND AreaLocation LIKE '%'+@AreaLocation+'%'))
```

See comment below for supplying '' instead of NULL arguments.  Otherwise the conditions get way too ugly, e.g.:

```
  AND (@AreaLocation = '' OR @AreaLocation IS NULL
       OR ((@AreaLocation != '' AND @AreaLocation IS NOT NULL)
            AND AreaLocation LIKE '%'+@AreaLocation+'%'))
```

Comment: please write complete query that can fulfill the scenario.

Comment: i think condition you have written will not fulfill because it will not skip any condition from where clause if value entered in text box is ' ' or null.your query is going to search null form db table ..as i mentioned in question; condition in where clause should skip if value is null

Comment: How can the data be '' or NULL? If a box is left blank, what value is assigned to the variable? Your input should write one of the 2 to the variable, not both. The above works well assuming an empty text box would set the variable to ''. Or are you indicating a single space rather than a blank value? `''` or `' '`

Comment: You can add checking for NULL, but text boxes should have zero length strings in them rather than no strings; or, your code that supplies the parameters to the SQL can supply '' if the argument is NULL. Otherwise the query gets really ugly. Example above.

Comment: ok .leave null or ' ' (empty string) a side .i have tried both with similar result .....with above query i have to search .what i need in where clause is if attribute value is not provided then query clause consider it as it not part where clause.and if non of attribute value is provided for where clause.query simply consider where clause does not exit because it where clause attribute value is no provided....How to write query for this situation ?

Comment: the problem is I am developing wpf application.I have to write that query in report viewer data-set.as i am using sqlite so i cant use  stored procedure or C# code . I can only write query here

Comment: The above query will ignore the cases in the WHERE clause when the argument string is ''.  Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @getche The above code does what you're asking. If the text box for the variable is left blank, then it will still return the results. If you're running what Doug provided and it's not giving you the results you're expecting, can you at least supply us with a sample table complete with data for us to test against?

Comment: Why do you need the `@param` != '', is `(@param == '' OR @param == param)` not enough ?I would had null condition too , though

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to test if the parameter is an empty string so you can do

```
AND (@param IS NULL OR @param = '' OR @param = param)
```

Answer (score 0):

At-last i made the query that fulfill my requirements

```
SELECT        Cust_Id, Clients_Title, Card_Number, Key_Person, Address_Current, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, AreaLocation
FROM            Customer_New
    where        (CASE
        WHEN @Clients_Title != ''   THEN Clients_Title=@Clients_Title
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
      AND(CASE
        WHEN @Address_Current != '' THEN Address_Current =@Address_Current
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
              AND(CASE
        WHEN @Phone_Number != '' THEN Phone_Number=@Phone_Number
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
      AND(CASE
        WHEN @Mobile_Number != '' THEN Mobile_Number=@Mobile_Number
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
      AND(CASE
        WHEN @AreaLocation != '' THEN AreaLocation =@AreaLocation
      ELSE
         NULL IS NULL
      END)
```